# Convert Long to Array of Integer Nums

Tags: c#, arrays, types, long-integer

How could I convert a long such as:

`123456789123456789`

into:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

I ask because I need a way to iterate through a Long in C sharp, but Long apparently doesn't use `[ ]` for arrays, so I can't seem to access each number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty crude, but you could convert the long into a string and then break it up into single digits and convert them back to integers like this

```
var digits = 123456789123456789L.ToString().Select(d => int.Parse(d.ToString()));
```

To convert back from an array to a long, you can do

```
var longFromDigits = digits.Aggregate(0L, (s, d) => s * 10 + d);
```

Comment: How can I turn it back into a Long again?

Comment: You mean go from an array of ints to a long?

Comment: Should be an extension method, but the implementation is pretty decent

Comment: @user769321: in the spirit of the solution it can be `long result = long.Parse(string.Concat(digits));`: here we concat all digits into `string`, then we parse it to `long`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to operate with `string`s you can just loop over digits with a help of modulo arithmetics:

```
public static int[] Digits(long value) {
  if (value == 0)
    return new int[] { 0 };

  List<int> result = new List<int>();

  for (; value != 0; value /= 10)
    result.Add((int)Math.Abs(value % 10));

  result.Reverse();

  return result.ToArray();
}
```

then

```
int[] digits = Digits(123456789123456789L);
```

**Edit:** All you have to do is to `Aggregate` the `digits` to have the `long` back:

```
int[] digits = new [] { 1, 2, 3};

long result = digits.Aggregate(0L, (s, a) => s * 10 + a);
```

Comment: why all that clutter? why not just do    `while (num != 0) { result.Insert(0, num % 10); num = num / 10; }`

Comment: @styx: in general case (not here) `result.Insert(0, ...)` is *time consuming*: we have to shift the entire collection, while `Add` followed by final `Reverse` is much faster on a huge data (not here, for sure). It's my habbit: longer code, but I sure it'll not betray me. Same for `Math.Abs` and a special case when `value == 0`